# Use of "approximately" in a sentence. How should I write this?

Tags: word-usage, word-order, sentence-structure

I want to convey that exactly a certain amount of time has passed in a scenario but I'm uncertain as to how to properly write it. Should I use "approximately"? And if so, where should I place it. For example,

> "**Approximately**, nine days, twelve hours and thirty-seven minutes had passed since they last spoke."

Like this? Is approximately even necessary? What else could I replace it with?

Comment: Please look up the term [*approximate*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/approximate) in an online dictionary

Comment: Also, there shouldn't be a comma between *approximately* and the amount of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't sound very approximate to me :) Although I suppose you could have counted the seconds as well ...

I'm sure this is not an English thing.  Every culture has words for estimation that vary in the degree of what they consider an "approximation".  In this case, a variance of a few seconds over the course of nearly ten days isn't very *approximate*.  It's more *exact*.

Instead consider these examples:

> He is *approximately* six feet tall.
>
> A marathon is *approximately* 42 kilometers.

If you want to be specific, use *exact* instead:

> He is exactly six foot three inches tall.
>
> A marathon is exactly 42.195 kilometers.

Of course you can use "approximately" as a joke, in contrast to a specific number.

> It's been approximately nine days, twelve hours and thirty-seven minutes since we last spoke.  Give or take a few seconds.

In place of "approximately" you could use "more or less", or "give or take".

> He is six feet tall, more or less.
>
> A marathon is 42 kilometers, give or take a couple hundred meters.

Comment: Ohhh. I see where I was wrong. Though can I even delete a post on here?

Comment: No need.  It's been put on hold so it won't get any more answers.  Glad I could be of help.